# Undesired overflow of CSS columns

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve something like this:
[image: Desired result]

But currently, I'm only getting this:

[image: Actual result]

Explanation (thanks Andrei Gheorghiu):

> I want to display the items in an indefinite number of inline columns,
>   the rule being "no more than 2 items in 1 column". The 3rd item
>   creates the second column, the 5th creates the 3rd one, the 7th
>   creates the 4th columns and so on. 
>   Either each column or the whole list must behave like inline block.

To sum up:

- The goal is to have two list items in each column.
- The whole list needs to be in the middle of paragraph - can't insert new lines 
  before or after.
- The number of items in the list is unknown.

Here's my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/2uf951km/6/

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  column-width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 
      Setting margin fixes the issue, 
      but the with of the list is not
      known.
     */
  /* margin-right: 170px; */
}

li {
  background: #9eff80;
  padding: 2px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div>
  I'd like to have a list with several columns
  <ul>
    <li>A list</li>
    <li>like this</li>
    <li>with unknown</li>
    <li>number and items</li>
    <li>or columns.</li>
  </ul>
  in the middle of other text.
</div>
```

How can my CSS/HTML be modified so the `<ul>` list wouldn't be covering the text?

Comment: @Jake I'll be converting it to PDF so SEO is not a concern. I haven't tried `::before`/`::after`, but I don't see how they could be helpful here. Can you post some code pls?

Comment: What you want is not possible. Should work by setting a `max-height` and `display:inline-flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: column` on `ul` and `width` on `li`, but it produces the result you came to. All things considered, it is a poor design decision in the first place. Give up having it inline and display the entire thing centered.

Comment: It can be done with JavaScript: take the `<ul>` and transform it into multiple elements each containing 2 items, displayed as `inline-block`s. Done! If you don't know JS, I can write it (it's trivial). Acceptable solution?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Well, it's the best solution so far, even though I was hoping for a solution without JS. I can write it, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer to achieve your goals using CSS Grid `inline-grid` to generate an inline level grid:**

`grid-template-rows` is set to repeat a maximum of two rows with `1fr` each.

`grid-template-columns` is set to repeat a `auto` number of columns necessary with a width of `35px`.

`grid-auto-flow` is set to `column` to have the grid auto-placement algorithm to fill in each column in turn, adding new columns as necessary while still keeping the maximum of two rows.

`grid-column-gap` was used to add padding between columns to display the same results as the images provided.

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

ul {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto, 35px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li {
  background: #9eff80;
  padding: 2px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div>
  I'd like to have a list with several columns
  <ul>
    <li>A list</li>
    <li>like this</li>
    <li>with unknown</li>
    <li>number and items</li>
    <li>or columns.</li>
  </ul>
  in the middle of other text.
</div>
```

Hope this solves your problem!

---

If your goal is to have a maximum of 3 counts of `columns` as shown in the images provided, I believe the property you need to change is:

`column-width: 35px` to **`columns: auto 3`** if you want the `column-width` of each column be set to `auto`.

or

`column-width: 35px` to **`columns: 35px 3`** if you want a specific `column-width` for each column.

This an explanation of what the `columns` property does:

> The **`columns`** CSS property sets the column width and column count of an element. - [MDN - css columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)

Bellow is the code I used to achieve the same result as the image you provided.

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  columns: auto 3;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li {
  background: #9eff80;
  padding: 2px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div>
  I'd like to have a list with several columns
  <ul>
    <li>A list</li>
    <li>like this</li>
    <li>with unknown</li>
    <li>number and items</li>
    <li>or columns.</li>
  </ul>
  in the middle of other text.
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe you got this wrong, as everyone else, because it wasn't clearly explained: OP wants to display the items in an indefinite number of inline columns, the rule being "no more than 2 items in 1 column". The 3rd item creates the second column, the 5th creates the 3rd one, the 7th creates the 4th columns and so on. Each column should behave like an inline block.

Comment: Thanks Christian for you answer. @AndreiGheorghiu got it right. The number of columns is indefinite. The problem with this solution is that it creates 2 columns even when only one is necessary. Do you think you could edit this solution to act the way Andrei explained?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu @Draex_ Thank you for your input and feedback. I have edited my answer to use CSS `display: inline-grid`, which I believe achieves Andrei's explanation and the goals of the original question.

Comment: Good idea, @Christian. Unfortunately, the grid behaves like one inline block, not like a series of inline blocks (columns wrap as a whole element and do not wrap when device width is smaller than grid's width). My conclusion is that what OP wants is not possible using CSS alone.

Answer (score 3):

**Initial answer** (before I realized what it is you're asking):

Depending on how you want `<li>`s ordered you can use [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)...

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  column-width: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  columns: 2 0px;
}

li {
  background: #9eff80;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 2px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  I'd like to have a list with several columns
  <ul>
    <li>A list</li>
    <li>like this</li>
    <li>with unknown</li>
    <li>number and items</li>
    <li>or columns.</li>
  </ul>
  in the middle of other text.
</div>
```

... or `display:inline-flex`. You'll need to set the `max-width` on children, set `flex-wrap: wrap` on the parent and specify desired `vertical-align` on the parent:

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  line-height: 5em;
  vertical-align: middle; 
     /* see also -webkit-baseline-middle
                 text-bottom
                 text-top */
}

li {
  line-height: 1em;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  margin: 1px;
  width: calc(50% - 2px); /*deduct margin*/
  background: #9eff80;
  padding: 2px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  I'd like to have a list with several columns
  <ul>
    <li>A list</li>
    <li>like this</li>
    <li>with unknown</li>
    <li>number and items</li>
    <li>or columns.</li>
  </ul>
  in the middle of other text.
</div>
```

Probably the most important part of it all is removing `height: 35px;` from `ul`. Why did you hardcode that anyway, if *"The number of items in the list is unknown"* ?

---

**Proper answer** (how it can be achieved):

It looks like you want your elements to be displayed as indefinite series of inline blocks, each containing 2 elements or less. You still have to define what should happen when the contents of your 2 elements exceeds the desired height of `35px`.

Here's how you can achieve it using vanilla JavaScript. If possible, you should do it on server side, though:

```js
let uls = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
for(let i = 0; i < uls.length; i++) {
  let count = uls[i].children.length;
  if (count && count > 2) {
    for (j = 0; j < count/2; j++) {
      let parent = uls[i].parentElement,
          newUl = document.createElement('ul');
      for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        li = uls[i].querySelector(':first-child');
        if (li) {
          newUl.appendChild(li);
          parent.insertBefore(newUl, uls[i]);
        }        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 35px;
}

li {
  background: #9eff80;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div>
  I'd like to have a list with several columns
  <ul>
    <li>A list</li>
    <li>like this</li>
    <li>with unknown</li>
    <li>number and items</li>
    <li>or columns.</li>
    <li>A list</li>
    <li>like this</li>
    <li>with unknown</li>
    <li>number and items</li>
    <li>or columns.</li>
    <li>A list</li>
  </ul>
  in the middle of other text.   I'd like to have a list with several columns
  <ul>
    <li>A list</li>
    <li>like this</li>
    <li>with unknown</li>
    <li>number and items</li>
    <li>or columns.</li>
    <li>A list</li>
    <li>like this</li>
    <li>with unknown</li>
    <li>number and items</li>
    <li>or columns.</li>
    <li>A list</li>
  </ul>
  in the middle of other text.
</div>
```

This is one of the cases where jQuery would be way shorter:

```js
$('ul').each(function() {
  while($('li', this).length > 2) {
    let newUl = $('<ul/>'), i = 0;
    while(i < 2) {
      $('li', this).eq(0).appendTo(newUl); 
      i++;
    }
    newUl.insertBefore($(this));
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several fixes, either add `display: block` to the `ul` like this

```css
 ul {
    display: block;
    column-width: 35px;
    height: 35px;

    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 10px;

    vertical-align: middle;

    /* 
        Setting margin fixes the issue, 
        but the with of the list is not
        known.
    */
    /* margin-right: 170px; */
}
```

Or change the `margin-right` to % or vw instead of px like this

```css
  ul {
    display: inline-block;
    column-width: 35px;
    height: 35px;

    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 10px;

    vertical-align: middle;

    /* 
        Setting margin fixes the issue, 
        but the with of the list is not
        known.
    */
    margin-right: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Hey. Unfortunately neither of these solve the problem. Setting `display: block` forces the list to be on separate line. Setting `margin-right` solves the problem for a specific content of the list, but if couple items are added/removed, it doesn't work well anymore.

Comment: what about  adding `display: inline-block;` to the `li` styling?

Comment: Doesn't help by itself. But if you have any other ideas, you can try for yourself here! https://jsfiddle.net/uwy21kp3/

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind having each `<li>` in it's own column, I think this might work:

```css
ul {
  display: inline;
  ...
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need two `<li>`'s in one column to save space.